# Django rest framework how to create 3 nested-serializer objects?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, nested, postman

I'm trying to create nested objects in Django Rest Framework according to the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

this my models.py :

```
from django.db import models


class Request(models.Model):
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class RequestOrders(models.Model):
    request_id = models.ForeignKey(Request, related_name='request_orders', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    order_ref = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id


class RequestOrderItemss(models.Model):
    request_order_id = models.ForeignKey(RequestOrders, related_name='request_order_itemss', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey('product.Product', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    qty = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

Here's my serializers.py :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from request.models import Request, RequestOrders, RequestOrderItemss
from product.serializers import ProductSerializer


class RequestOrderItemssSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RequestOrderItemss
        fields = ('id', 'request_order_id', 'product_id', 'qty')


class RequestOrdersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    request_order_itemss = RequestOrderItemssSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = RequestOrders
        fields = ('id', 'request_id', 'position', 'destination', 'order_ref', 'request_order_itemss')


class RequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    request_orders = RequestOrdersSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ('id', 'origin', 'request_orders')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        request_orders_data = validated_data.pop('request_orders')
        request = Request.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for request_order_data in request_orders_data:
            request_order_items_data = request_order_data.pop('request_order_itemss')
            request_order = RequestOrders.objects.create(request_id=request,
                                                                        **request_order_data)
            for request_order_item_data in request_order_items_data:
                RequestOrderItemss.objects.create(request_order_id=request_order,
                                                         **request_order_item_data)
        return request

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        request_orders_data = validated_data.pop('request_orders')
        orders = instance.request_orders.all()
        orders = list(orders)
        instance.origin = validated_data.get('origin', instance.origin)
        instance.save()

        for request_order_data in request_orders_data:
            request_order_items_data = request_order_data.pop('request_order_itemss')
            items = instance.request_orders.get().request_order_itemss.all()
            items = list(items)
            for request_order_item_data in request_order_items_data:
                item = items.pop(0)
                item.product_id = request_order_item_data.get('product_id', item.product_id)
                item.qty = request_order_item_data.get('qty', item.qty)
                item.save()
            order = orders.pop(0)
            order.position = request_order_data.get('position', order.position)
            order.destination = request_order_data.get('destination', order.destination)
            order.order_ref = request_order_data.get('order_ref', order.order_ref)
            order.save()
        return instance
```

and this is my views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from request.models import Request, RequestOrders, RequestOrderItemss
from request.serializers import RequestSerializer, RequestOrdersSerializer, \
    RequestOrderItemssSerializer


class RequestListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Request.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RequestSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


class RequestView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = RequestSerializer
    queryset = Request.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


class RequestOrdersListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = RequestOrders.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RequestOrdersSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


class RequestOrdersView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = RequestOrdersSerializer
    queryset = RequestOrders.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


class RequestOrderItemssListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = RequestOrderItemss.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RequestOrderItemssSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


class RequestOrderItemssView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = RequestOrderItemssSerializer
    queryset = RequestOrderItemss.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

this is my JSON data that i want to save in data base :

```
{
"origin": "Krishna Rungta",
"request_orders": [
    {
        "position":"2",
        "destination" :"Paris",
        "order_ref":"ref#123",
        "request_order_itemss":[
            {
                "product_id":4,
                "qty":444,
            }
            {
                "product_id":5,
                "qty":33,
            }
        ]
    }
    {
        "position":"3",
        "destination" :"Paris",
        "order_ref":"ref#124",
        "request_order_itemss":[
            {
                "product_id":6,
                "qty":123,
            }
            {
                "product_id":4,
                "qty":54,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

when I try to test this on Postman I get this error :

> Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited.
> Use request_order_itemss.set() instead.

So I want to know where is the problem and is what i did is right or is there something wrong.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It would be easier to debug with a full stack trace.  Also, where are these "Loading..." models?  I'm having a hard time understanding the references to `LoadingRequest`, `loading_request_order_itemss`, etc.  That said, I would guess that the problem you are seeing is a result of the fact that you are not actually ever calling the nested create method (in `RequestSerializer`, you just create `RequestOrders` objects without deserializing the validated data first).

Comment: apa yang terjadi on your model, LoadingRequestOrders and LoadingRequest???

Comment: @RishiG sorry, i edited the model i made some changes but i forget to change all but i don't know where problem is. Can you explain it to me.

Comment: You still have a call to `LoadingRequest.objects.create` in `RequestSerializer`, and you also have not provided an actual stack trace as I suggested, but I think I have a handle on the problem and will answer as well as I can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The error

The problem here is that you have a twice-nested model, but you are only actually deserializing one layer of it before trying to create the objects.  You have created `RequestOrderItemssSerializer` and `RequestOrdersSerializer` classes, but you are not actually using them in the `create` method.  If you POST the given JSON object to the `/requests/` endpoint, the view will call `RequestSerializer.create` with the that same object. In your `create` method, you will then call `RequestOrders.objects.create` with, e.g.,

```py
request_order_data = {
    "position":"2",
    "destination" :"Paris",
    "order_ref":"ref#123",
    "request_order_itemss": [
        {
            "product_id":4,
            "qty":444,
        }
        {
            "product_id":5,
            "qty":33,
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the list `request_order_itemss` has not been properly deserialized and the items have not been created, which is why you are getting the error about trying to directly assign values to the reverse side of the `RequestOrderItemss.request_order_id` `ForeignKey` relationship.

Note that the example you pointed to in the docs is designed to show you how to handle this exact error, but only for a single level of hierarchy (creating the individual tracks for a given album).

#### Simple Solution

The simplest way to solve this, is to do away with the `RequestOrderSerializer` and `RequestOrderItemsSerializer` and just add an inner loop to the `Request.create` method which handles the second nested part.  Something like this:

```py
class RequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        request_orders_data = validated_data.pop('request_orders')
        request = Request.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for request_order_data in request_orders_data:
            ro_items = request_order_data.pop('request_order_itemss')
            order = RequestOrders.objects.create(request_id=request, **request_order_data)
            for ro_item in ro_items:
                RequestOrderItemss.create(request_order_id=order, **ro_item)
        return request
```

I won't implement and test this, so there are probably bugs in the code as written here, but the concept should be straightforward enough.  I've also only handled the `create` method, but you should be able to treat `update` by extension.

Comment: I create the update method but i get this error "get() returned more than one RequestOrders -- it returned 2!" when i try to update more than one Request_Order (it works when i update just one). I edit my serializer to see the update method that i create it. can you help me?

Comment: This is not the place for it.  Post a new question with the code and a full stack trace.  See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for suggestions on how to ask a good question